# How to put multiple charsets at one position in hashcat?

Tags: hashcat

I want to search for all letters and some special characters at the same time

```
?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?ludhHs?lludhHs
```

Something like this for a 9 Letter password with all characters. Does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [built-in charset](http://%20?a%20=%20?l?u?d?s) `?a`, which is a shortcut for `?l?u?d?s`.

Try out this command:
`hashcat -a 3 -m 0 your.hash ?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a`

Don't forget to swap out the mode and hash file for whatever you are cracking.

---

If you really were trying to use a [custom charset](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack#custom_charsets) with `?l` and the characters `udhHs`, that's mostly redundant since `?l` is already all the lowercase letters, but here's an example for that custom charset:

`hashcat -a 3 -1 ?ludhHs -m 0 your.hash ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1`